# Invalid hook call problem. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i want to create todo app using react i use the useContext hook but i get the following problem

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import TodoStore from './Hooks/TodoStore'
import './App.css'
import TodosForm from './Component/TodosForm'
import Tasks from './Component/Tasks'

function App() {
  const [todolist,setTodoList] = useState([]);
  const fillTodoList = (todo) => {
    setTodoList([todo,...todolist])
  }
  return (
    <TodoStore.Provider value={setTodoList}>
    <TodosForm fillTodoList={fillTodoList} />
    <Tasks alltasks={todolist} setList={setTodoList}/>
    </TodoStore.Provider>
  )
}

export default App
```

```
import React from 'react'
import Completed from '../Operations/Completed'
import deleteTask from '../Operations/deleteTask'

function Tasks(props) {
  return (
    <div>
        {
            props.alltasks.map((item)=><div  key={item.id}>
            <span onClick={()=>Completed(item.id,props.alltasks)}>{item.text}</span>
            <button onClick={()=>deleteTask(item.id,props.alltasks)}>X</button>
            </div>)
        }
       
    </div>
  )
}

export default Tasks
```

```
import { useContext } from "react"
import TodoStore from "../Hooks/TodoStore"

const deleteTask = (id,alltasks) => {
  const {setList}=useContext(TodoStore);
  const result=alltasks.filter((item)=>item.id!=id)
  setList([...result])
}
export default deleteTask
```

Comment: You are calling useContext in deleteTask which is neither a custom hook nor a function component, and so violates the rules of hooks.

Comment: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: this is the exact example of https://react.dev/learn/scaling-up-with-reducer-and-context for using context and reducer. see the above link and see what you should do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your `deleteTask` function: you are using a hook (`useContext`) but this function is not a hook by itself.

You have to understand that React have to render the exact [same amount of hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) for each render of a component. So you cannot use a hook inside a nested function (except if it's also a hook)

## The best way

Use a [reducer](https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer) inside your context so you don't have to write multiple operation to modify your context. It's the base of the [Flux pattern](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-introduction-to-the-flux-architectural-pattern-674ea74775c9/). It will allow you to have a more concise and more evolutive code.

## The quickest (and a little bit dirty) way

You can transform your `deleteTask` function to a custom hook and use it inside your Tasks component

```
import { useContext } from "react"
import TodoStore from "../Hooks/TodoStore"

// Note that hook must always starts with "use"
const useDeleteTask = () => {
    const {setList} = useContext(TodoStore);
    return (id, alltasks) => {
        const result = alltasks.filter((item) => item.id != id)
        setList([...result])
    }
}
export default useDeleteTask
```

Your Task component

```
function Tasks(props) {
    const deleteTask = useDeleteTask()
    return (
        <div>
            {
                props.alltasks.map((item) => <div key={item.id}>
                    <span onClick={()=>Completed(item.id,props.alltasks)}>{item.text}</span>
                    <button onClick={() => deleteTask(item.id,props.alltasks)}>X</button>
                </div>)
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

*Note that you don't have to pass the `allTodos` props as it's part of your context so you can get it with `useContext`.*

Hope it will solve your problem.